# Ember-CLI extend a custom route (as a base "class")

Tags: inheritance, ember.js, routes, ember-cli

I'm using Ember-CLI to develop my Ember App.

I have a "super" route (in routes/authenticate.js), like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

I want to make it the base class for some other routes in my app, like this (route/home.js):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
});
```

It doesn't work. Console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined

Ember-CLI guide doesn't have any word on this scenario (which I believe is essential).

Anyone know how to do it correctly and in the most simple way?

Thanks,
Raka

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/base-route-in-ember-cli/7103

```
import Authenticated from './authenticated';

export default Authenticated.extend({
});
```